# Counting and deleting multiple Elements in a nested Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

this is the structure of my array:

```
arrayParent = [numbers, counter];

numbers = [1,1,1,2,4,5];
counter = [];
```

what I want to do is counting multiple elements in "numbers" and pushing to "counter" while deleting in the first, in the end it should look like this:

```
numbers = [1,2,4,5];
counter = [3,1,1,1];
```

I tried this ( and many many other versions):

```
for(var y =0; y < arrayParent.length; y++){
 for(var x = 0; x < arrayParent[y].numbers.length; x++){
    var co = 1;
    for(var z = x+1; z < arrayParent[y].numbers.length; z++){
      if(arrayParent[y].numbers[x] == arrayParent[y].ans[z]){
          co++;
          arrayParent[y].numbers.splice(z);
          arrayParent[y].counter[x] = co;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

The result I got:

```
numbers = [1,2,4,5];
counter = [3,,,];
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Not clear. What is the expected output for `numbers = (2,1,1,1,2,4,5);`

Comment: it should be numbers=(2,1,4,5) counter = ( 2,3,1,1) .. counter shows how many doublets were found in the array, in the numbers output those doublets are deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like:

```js
let numbers = [1,1,1,2,4,5];
let counter = [];

const tmp = numbers.reduce((res, curr) => ({
  ...res,
  [curr]: (res[curr] || 0) + 1
}), {});

numbers = Object.keys(tmp).map(Number);
counter = Object.values(tmp);

console.log(numbers, counter);
```

so, I created a counter object where keys are distinct numbers and values are their counter

As @nikhil correctly noticed this method will not preserve numbers order, to preserve it, just change JS object to JS Map, the logic is the same:

```js
let numbers = [1,1,1,2,5, 4];
let counter = [];

const tmp = numbers.reduce((res, curr) => res.set(curr, (res.get(curr) || 0) + 1), new Map());

numbers = [...tmp.keys()];
counter = [...tmp.values()];

console.log(numbers, counter);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've come up with as well.

Comment: It will sort the keys based on number i.e. `numbers = (2,1,1,1,2,4,5);` it will result in `numbers = (1, 2,4,5);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
let arrayParent = {numbers : [1,1,1,2,4,5], counter : []};
// This will ensure that the order of elements is same as in the array
let order = [];
// Create an object with key as `number` and counts as its value
let map = arrayParent.numbers.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(a[c]) a[c]++;
  else {a[c] = 1; order.push(c); }
  return a;
}, new Map());
// Set the value of order in numbers
arrayParent.numbers = order;
// Set the counts in counter
order.forEach(o => arrayParent.counter.push(map[o]));

console.log(arrayParent);
```